# What is the convergence value of series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i^2 * (0.4)^i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

One technique to cope with some series is using derivation of a geometry series. But in this case I think $i^2$ makes this technique useless.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: You may use $i^2=i(i-1)+i$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{C}:\|x\|<1,\qquad\sum_{n\geq 1}x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}\tag{1} $$
Now we apply twice the operator $xD: f(x)\mapsto x\cdot f'(x) $ to get:
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{C}:\|x\|<1,\qquad\sum_{n\geq 1}n^2\,x^n = \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}\tag{2} $$
and by evaluating at $x=\frac{2}{5}$:

> $$\sum_{n\geq 1}n^2\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n = \color{red}{\frac{70}{27}}.\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Unless I made a mistake in calculations...
$$S = \sum_{i \ge 1} i^2(0.4)^i = 0.4 + S*0.4 + 0.4*\sum_{i \ge 1}((i+1)^2-i^2)(0.4)^i \\
S' = \sum_{i \ge 1}i(0.4)^i = 0.4 + S'*0.4 + 0.4*\sum_{i \ge 1}(i+1 - i)(0.4)^i \\
S' = {2 \over 3}(1 + 0.4/0.6) = {10 \over 9} \\
S = {2 \over 3}(1+2S'+0.4/0.6) = {70 \over 27}$$